# Putting 3 buttons in parallel

Tags: css, html

This is my code where I am trying to put 3 Buttons in parallel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<div class="aParent">
 <div id="left_side">
   <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/new" data-remote="true" method="get"><div    style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
   <label for="q">Make A new folder:</label><br>
   <input id="q" name="q" type="text" /><br>
   <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form></div>
<div id="centre">
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Save" action="update" alignment="center" />
</div>
<div id="right_side">
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/target" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
 <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Customize Weight" />
</form></div>
</div>

 <style type="text/css">

  #left_side {
  float: left;
    }

  #center_s {
   margin:50px 50px;
   width: 65px;
    }

  #right_side {
   float: right;
    }


     </style>
```

Now if I change margin values save button position is not changing . Any guesses for changes to be made to put 3 buttons in parallel.

Comment: I only see two buttons, so that would be rather difficult to achive :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
 #centre{ float:left;}
```

If you're looking to centre this `div`, you will need to add an appropriate `margin-left` value, so long as your parent container is of fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

add `display:inline-block` to all the three container div and remove the `float` property.

```
#left_side {
    display: inline-block;
}

#center_s {
    margin: 50px 50px;
    width: 65px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#right_side {
    background: Green;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[<kbd>Js Fiddle Example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/MgPc2/1/)

You have some complex html structure to do this simple thing as you can achieve without using the css and just you need to put simple markup like this

```
<div class="aParent">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/new" data-remote="true" method="get">
    <div id="label">
            <label for="q">Make A new folder:</label>
    </div>
    <div id="input-control">
            <input id="q" name="q" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="button-control">
            <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input id="btn" type="button" value="Save" action="update" alignment="center" />
            <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Customize Weight" />
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[<kbd>Js Fiddle - Simple design</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/MgPc2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just put all 3 divs {float: left} and then add a small margin to them to separate them?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this:

1.You can float the elements you want to position. Add a line in the css code, for example

```
#center_s {
margin: 50px 50px;
width: 65px;
float: left; 
}
```

**This will change the element model from box to inline**.

Using `float` will stack the elements next to one another.

You can read this great article about float property - http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

1. You can change the display property to `inline-block` - add a new css property - `display: inline block;` to all three elements.

This will change the div from block model to inline model!
Another great article about display property - http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

Hope this answered your question.